# Switched capacitors in an op-amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, homework, switched-capacitor

[image: Task]

I am having trouble solving part (b) of this task.
I would expect to achieve charge conservation equations, but considering that the inverting input of the op-amp is shorted with the output terminal of the op-amp during phase 2, there are no charges being conserved during that phase.

In this case, how do we find the transfer function of V<sub>out</sub>/V<sub>in</sub>?

Answer (score 0):

The gain equation is the ratio of the two capacitors:

- Vout = -(C1 / C2) * Vin

That is, the bigger the switched capacitor, the lower the modeled resistance.

More about that here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/an-introduction-to-switched-capacitor-circuits/

Example: if C1 is twice as large as C2, C2 has to be charged up to *twice* the voltage of C1 to balance the C1 - C2 charge transfer. Therefore it will have a gain of 2.

Switched cap op-amp circuits have a neat party trick, too: gain polarity is selectable by swapping phases.

Comment: I assume You derived the gain only by looking at the circuit configuration during phase 1. Only during this phase we have a conservation of charges at the negative input of the op-amp. So in that sense, we can ignore phase 2 where the charges are not conserved? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: During P2 the charges on C1 and C2 are dumped and the circuit is reset. During P1 current flows through both C1 and C2, and the final voltage across each cap is proportional to 1/C of each one. So if C1 = 2C2, then VC1 = 2VC2.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank You very much!